# Does a bear sh*t in the woods? Rhetorical affirmations in Japanese. Is there any?

Tags: expressions, slang, culture, rhetorical-questions

I could not find anything on this website nor with a (quick I admit) search on Google.

Does Japanese have any "yes phrase" (or more technically rhetorical affirmation) used to answer questions whose answer is supposed to be an obvious "yes"? Such as:

> Does a bear sh*t in the woods?
>
> Is the pope catholic?

In fact, these expressions are so common in English that you can often find them twisted in comical ways:

> Is the Space Pope reptilian? (Futurama)
>
> Is the atomic weight of Cobalt 58.9? (Ghostbusters II)

Given that sarcasm is generally is not a typical trait of Japanese people, maybe something like this doesn't exist. Or does it? Anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This famous phrase from a manga](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%88%E3%81%AF%E4%BB%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%83%91%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E6%9E%9A%E6%95%B0%E3%82%92%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BC%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B%3F) instantly came to my mind, but probably this was created intentionally so that it would sound like a "typical American joke", and I don't think it's used outside otaku communities. I could not think of a more traditional expression similar to this. A classic set expression for "obviously true" is [火を見るより明らか](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%81%AB%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E6%98%8E%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B) (mainly used in written Japanese), but this does not sound sarcastic or humorous at all.